# Matrix multiplication in Forward Propogation for Handritten Digit Recog Algo inefficient

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision, matrix-multiplication

I am writing a handwritten digit recognition neural network algorithm in python, without using prewritten ML libraries. I am currently attempting to implement a DenseLayer class and within it a forward propogation function. My current function can be seen below.

```
class DenseLayer:
  ...
  
  ...
  def for_prop(self, input_data):
    self.input = input_data

    transpose_weights = self.weights.T
    # matMulComponent = np.matmul(input_data, transpose_weights)
    print(f"transpose shape: {transpose_weights.shape} and input shape {input_data.shape}")
    matMulComponent = input_data.T @ transpose_weights
    print(len(matMulComponent))

    z = matMulComponent + self.biases.T
    f_wb = self.act_fun(z)
    
    

    self.output = f_wb.reshape(-1, 1)
    print(f"result of shape: {self.output.shape}")
    return self.output
```

The issue is I am doing a lot of reshaping and transposing to get my result. This doesnt seem efficient.

So my question is:

- is this fine to implement (ergo will it cause innefficiencies)
- Is there a better way to do this forward propogation function

This is what my input data array looks like (i just printed it and took a ss). My input data for reference is a flattened 28*28 array with each cell representing a colour. I first normalised the data (z-score noramlisation)

[Input data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUZNs.png)

I also have taken a screenshot of my weight format for the first layer if that helps. (keep in mind it is transposed before use in the for_prop function).

[picture of weights matrix for first hidden layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02WBS.png)

Forward propogation does seem to be working though which is good:[Forward prop progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO1p4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Transposing and reshaping Numpy arrays is normally a fast operation, negligible when arrays are large.

Nevertheless, you can invert the array multiplication order and avoid some transpositions. It won't be much faster, but it may look better (not tested):

```
matMulComponent = self.weights @ input_data
z = matMulComponent + self.biases
```

In this case, `z` is transposed respect to your original implementations.